# Odoo Server Error when i try to install my module

Tags: xml, python-3.6, odoo, odoo-12

I'm new on python and odoo and i'm trying to build a module ,
i had this error when i try to install my module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-61>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 445, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 796, in convert_file
    with file_open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 199, in file_open
    return _fileopen(name, mode=mode, basedir=rtp, pathinfo=pathinfo, basename=basename)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 257, in _fileopen
    raise IOError('File not found: %s' % basename)
OSError: File not found: university\views/student_views.xml
```

PS :i'm using odoo 12 and its demo database 
and this the error i had on pycharm while running odoo_bin :

***2020-02-26 20:37:10,611 4160 ERROR odoo12 odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 421, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 796, in convert_file
    with file_open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\misc.py", line 199, in file_open
    raise IOError('File not found: %s' % basename)
OSError: File not found: university\views/student_views.xml
2020-02-26 20:37:10,627 4160 ERROR odoo12 odoo.http: Exception during JSON request handling. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise IOError('File not found: %s' % basename)
OSError: File not found: university\views/student_views.xml***

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Do you have a custom addon named university in which you have an xml file named student_views.xml well if not then you should remove view path from __manefest__.py file and if yes then recheck the path and update the module university from app list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`university\views/student_views.xml`

In the `__manifest__.py` file this view file path is provided, but isn't a valid path. Provide the `student_views.xml` file properly, note that this path has to be relative path from modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

In ****manifest**.py** file add the code like this,

```
**{
    'name': '<your module name>',
    'category' : '<category>',
    'application' : True,
'data':['views/student_views.xml'],
}**
```